# For Loop takes longer than number of loops multiplied by time to complete once

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a for loop that uses already defined functions and the result from the previous stage in the loop. It takes longer to run than the function once multiplied by the number of loops. Is there a more effective way?

```py
def Surge_Method2(CD, FlyWheel_frequence, Presession_frequence, slices, Time_Step, Stop_time):
    Advance_V = [0]

    for i in Elements(Time_Step, Stop_time):
        advance_v = Foward_Velocity(Advance_V[i], Roll_V_at_time(i*Time_Step, 
        FlyWheel_frequence, Presession_frequence), CD, slices, Time_Step) 

        Advance_V.append(advance_v)
        out = Advance_V[:-1]
    return(out)
```

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without knowing the implementations of `Elements`, `Forward_Velocity`, `Roll_V_at_time` etc which appear to be functions or classes? Have you analysed your run time complexity? One iteration of the loop could take considerably different time depending on the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bsa is right: You are perhaps making an assumption that your underlying functions always have the same execution time.

If your pre-defined functions are e.g. recursive or involve loops that depend on the number itself (use the analogy of the calculation of factorials) then their execution time would vary wildly. I would strongly advise that you benchmark each of them before benchmarking your function.

#### Not directly related to your question:

Idiomatic Python uses lowercase in the names of variables, so your function should rather be called `surge_method2()`, and the arguments `flywheel_frequence`, `presession_frequence`, etc.